Re initialize Bloc
I have a bloc that i registered in multibloc provider in main.dart under mutiblocprovider.
This bloc provider have functions that i need to work inside its constructor.
class BlocA extends Bloc<BlocAEvent, BlocAState> {
  BlocA({
    required this.repository,
    required this.userInfo
  }) : super(const BlocAState()) {

 // i have a functions here that uses userInfo.

on<Events>(_events);

}

But for some reason after the app loaded (homescreen after loggedIn), userInfo is empty, and it only contains record/data after hot reload.
I understood this because the BlocA won't be reinitialized because its already been initialized from the start.
Have you encountered the same scenario? what did you do to make it work.

If you can include full minimal snippet that can run and test, it will clear some doubt. from current context, ig if you override the the == operator/ or use Equitable it will solve the issue

Maybe you try to use a listener to listen to the event userInfo loaded (maybe EventBus) and re-run your desired function instead of finding a way to re-init bloc
